# C multidimensional arrays, incompatible assignment

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

Very specific problem, possibly due to my generally poor understanding of multidimensional arrays in C. I've got this code:

```
int io_pipes[NUM_IO_PROC][n][2][2];

for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    int pipes[NUM_IO_PROC][2][2];
    for (int j = 0; j < NUM_IO_PROC; ++j) pipes[j] = io_pipes[j][i];
}
```

There's some stuff missing, of course (like what happens to the `pipes` variable). Problem is that on line 5 there, I get a compiler error that say "incompatible type in assignment." I'd like it if the compiler gave me more information because as far as I know, `pipes[j]` and `io_pipes[j][i]` are both of type `int[2][2]`.

Comment: Do you want to copy the data, or just 'make pointers'?

Comment: I think more correctly `pipes[j]` and `io_pipes[j][i]` are both of type `const int[2][2]`, which means you cannot assign to `pipes[j]`.

Comment: I went with the struct version, which allows me to do exactly what I wanted rather than the memcpy version below, and makes better sense overall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot 'assign' arrays. (At least, what I *think* you're trying to do.)

You'll need to copy each element, one by one. Maybe you can use one of the existing library functions for this task?

```
for(int j = 0; j < NUM_IO_PROC; ++j)
    memcpy(&pipes[j], &io_pipes[j][i], sizeof pipes[j]);
```

Comment: `memcpy(&pipes[j], &io_pipes[j][i], sizeof pipes[j]);` is probably clearer.

Answer (score 0):

The arrays identifier is internally treadted as pointer to base address, but unlike pointers they cannot be assigned a new address value which you are trying to do in `pipes[j] = io_pipes[j][i];`